# How to not give user access to the login page when they are already logged in?

Tags: reactjs

https://pastebin.com/mXgqRP4j

I am trying to implement that when a user is logged in, the user has no access to the login page. To do that I have put an if condition at the end that if the user is authenticated, the user will be redirected to the dashboard even when they input the path to the login component. But whats happening is that when I input the link to the login page (I have routes set up), the login page shows up for a split second and then disappears and then the dashboard appears. What should have happened was that the user shouldve been redirected directly to the dashboard. Please guide me!

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Admin from "../../pages/Admin"
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
 
function AdminLogin() {
 
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    const [csrf, setCsrf] = useState('')
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    
 
    function getCsrf(){
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/csrf/", {
                credentials: "include",
              })
              .then((res) => {
                let csrfToken = res.headers.get("X-CSRFToken");
                setCsrf({csrf: csrfToken});
 
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
              })
    }
 
    const login = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
 
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/login/", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRFToken": csrf.csrf,
          },
          credentials: "include",
          body: JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password}),
        })
        .then(isResponseOk)
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          setIsAuthenticated(true)
          localStorage.setItem("authenticated", true);
          setUsername('')
          setPassword('')
 
        //   this.setState({isAuthenticated: true, username: "", password: ""});
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('inside login catch')
            console.log(csrf.csrf, 'catch')
          console.log(err);
        });
      }
 
      const isResponseOk = (response) =>{
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status <= 299) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          console.log(response)
          throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
      }
      useEffect(() => {
        //getSessions
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/session/", {
            credentials: "include",
          })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            // console.log(data);
            if (data.isAuthenticated) {
              setIsAuthenticated(true)
 
              console.log(data)
            } else {
 
              setIsAuthenticated(false)
              console.log(data)
 
              getCsrf()
            }})
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
 
 
      }, [])
 
      console.log(csrf);
      console.log(counter)
 
 
 
    const handleUsername = (e) => {
        setUsername(e.target.value)
    }
 
    const handlePassword = (e) => {
        setPassword(e.target.value)
    }
 
    const loginScreen =   (  
    <div className="login-box m-auto">
    <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body login-card-body">
        <p className="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>
        <form  method="post" onSubmit={login}>
            <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <input required type="text" value={username} onChange={handleUsername} className="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
            <div className="input-group-append">
                <div className="input-group-text">
                <span className="fas fa-envelope" />
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <input required type="password" value={password} onChange={handlePassword} className="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
            <div className="input-group-append">
                <div className="input-group-text">
                <span className="fas fa-lock" />
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
 
            <div className="col-4">
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>)
 
    if(isAuthenticated)
    {   
        return <Navigate replace to="/admin/dashboard" />;
    }
    else{
 
        return loginScreen
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create isLoading state alongside isAuthenticated state and initialize it with true and show the loading screen until checking authentication is finished and set isLoading to false. After that you can show the login screen only if isLoading is false and isAuthentcated is also false.

If it's okay to use Redux so I suggest using Redux-Persist and make it rehydrate the auth part so you will not face this issue.

Comment: I'll try that. Does <Navigate /> reload the page? Because I have noticed that the states go back to their initial value once I use <Navigate /> to redirect.

Comment: No it doesn't reload the page, it's just like if you clicked on <Link>